# Robotic simulator install issue

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

(Forwarded from [DRC Software Forum](http://forum.theroboticschallenge.org/index.php?topic=32.0))

Hi ,
I am new to ubuntu platform . I installed ubuntu 12.10 and i tried to install the simulator . while performing the step

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

i am getting a error "no valid openPGP data found"   . I will be grateful if any one can  help me to overcome this issue .
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/134/robotic-simulator-install-issue/) by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1414 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would guess that the `wget` command failed to download the key file, perhaps due to a network problem.  Try doing it in two steps:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O ros.key
sudo apt-key add ros.key
```

If there's a network problem, you should see it during the first step.  If you continue to have trouble with `wget`, try downloading that URI from a web browser.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-11**:
As far as I know, fuerte is not supported in quantal (12.10), we'll have to migrate drcsim to depend on groovy for this to work.  We are currently testing ros functionalities for drcsim in groovy.